# What does "Close existing connections" on SSMS "Delete Database" do?

Tags: sql-server-2008

What's the point of deleting a database while leaving the "existing connections" open? i.e., what's the purpose of those connections if there will be no database there? Shouldn't the connections be closed upon deleting the DB automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting that option will force any open connections to be killed before any attempt is made to delete the database; if there are open connections and you don't select this option, the delete will fail.

It's a bit of a safety net, I usually manually kill connections, and leave it unchecked, if I get errors on delete, I know someone or something reconnected recently, or I'm deleting the wrong database...